# Check last time internet connection was made

Tags: networking, dhcp, logfiles

I would like to know the last time my Raspberry Pi Zero (1.7W) was connected to the internet.

**OS:** Raspberry Pi OS Lite,
**Kernel version:** 5.15 &
**Debian version:** 11 (bullseye)

There was a similar question [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639182/how-can-i-reliably-check-which-is-the-last-time-an-ubuntu-machine-has-been-conne) using an Ubuntu machine. However, it has additional capabilities, i.e., a Network Manager. Seems like a solution could be analyzing the `/var/log/syslog` output but, I am unsure what to sift through using `awk` or `grep`.

My goal is to see that if the last time there has been a network connection, and it has has been greater than 18 hours run a script.

Thanks.

Comment: you may get better results by asking at a linux site, since your question is not really about Raspberry Pi

Comment: Check the connection pages on your router. Linux doesn't bother recording that info as it has no use or relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "connected to the internet".

All network managers (using DHCP) connect to a DHCP server (usually your router). `systemctl status dhcpcd` will show when Raspberry Pi OS obtained its lease.

The OS does NOT "connect to the internet" - various processes running may, but you would need to check these.

Probably the most frequent connection to the internet is done by timesyncd.

On Raspberry Pi OS `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` will show initial sync and `timedatectl timesync-status` will show detail.
On my system this shows `Poll interval: 34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)` i.e. 2048 seconds and `/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock` will show the time this was done.